# How to make this image embed code work with ajax pager

Tags: javascript

I have this little code that turns image links into embeds but it doesn't work with ajax paging on my forum, I have to refresh page for link to be turned into image embed.

```
$('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".tiff"], a[href$=".webp"]').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />');
});
```

I tried adding document ready but it didn't help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".tiff"], a[href$=".webp"]').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />');
  })
});
```

Comment: Well, you have to execute this code every time the AJAX call completes. Otherwise, this code only runs once after the page has loaded. By the way, it seems like you’re posting questions from two accounts (a recent question has nearly identical code: [How to fix this image embed code I'm working on](/q/74424709/4642212)). Make sure you follow the rules: [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/4642212).

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. do you have answer to my question?